# Error updating Angular with .NET Core 5 from version 11 to 12

Tags: node.js, angular, .net-core

I am having trouble migrating my Angular project from version 11 to version 12. I actually want to get to the latest version of Angular, but I figured that I would go step by step. The problem I'm having is that my project doesn't work anymore at version 12. I should mention that my project is .NET Core / Angular and I'm using Visual Studio.

Here are the steps that I took:

- `ng update @angular/core@12 @angular/cli@12`
- I then did `ng update` and `npm install`

I’m currently getting the error,

> throw new Error(errorMessage + 'NGCC failed${errorMessage ? ', see above' : ''}.'); in node_modules @ngtools\webpack\src\ngcc_processor.js

I tried changing my version of node from 14.15.0 to 18.13.0 but that did not fix the problem.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Hello. welcome to SO. Can you please post the error message, the package.json and angular.json files ?

Comment: Try showing your package.json code to have better perspective. As well remember that if you update your project, your package.json should update as well with your modules. See if some of your modules have conflicts with another one or try updating the module by yourself (not recommended).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.